# Spring 4.2 Data Visualization with Grafana via HTTP (No Postgres Direct Access)

Tags: spring, postgresql, model-view-controller, grafana, datasource

I have a Spring 4.2 application integrated with PostgreSQL for data storage. I want to visualize specific data using Grafana dashboards (e.g., bar graphs). Direct connection to the PostgreSQL database in Grafana is prohibited due to data privacy concerns. Health checks and additional monitoring tools like Prometheus are not required.**

What I want to achieve is to

Integrate my Spring application with Grafana using HTTP as the datasource. Retrieve data from PostgreSQL within the Spring application and expose it in a Grafana-compatible format (e.g., JSON). Utilize Grafana's built-in or plugin-based functionalities for data visualization.

Which Grafana datasource plugin would be most suitable for this scenario? What best practices should I follow to achieve the task?